# How to use IntelliTrace in Azure Development Fabric?

Tags: azure, intellitrace

When I create a new Azure solution (with a web role and a worker role), add a line of code to the Default.aspx.cs file, put a breakpoint there, and launch debugging in the Development Fabric, when the breakpoint is hit and I look at the Intellitrace tab, I am confronted with the following error message:

> Intellitrace is not collecting data for this debugging session. The project type may not be supported or the process you are debugging may have been either attached to or launched with IntelliTrace disabled. Restarting the debugging session within Visual Studio may solve this. Please note that IntelliTrace is not supported when attaching to a process that is already running. If you have selected a custom location for InteliTrace [sic] recordings, please make sure it is writable by the process being debugged.

The problem also occurs with other Azure solutions that I previously created. When I create a standard ASP .Net web application, I am able to use IntelliTrace without difficulty. I have tried this both without selecting a custom location for IntelliTrace recordings and using the same location that I used for a standard ASP .Net web application. I tried restarting the computer too. I also reinstalled the Windows Azure SDK. Because of concern that IntelliTrace might not work when SQL Server Debugging is enabled, I made sure that SQL Server Debugging was disabled on the worker role (the only project that had an option for this in the Debug tag of the project settings).

The closest resource on this question is [on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/4b5315f2-b52b-40a3-b428-8168c7ecd23d). The answer is unclear. It states, "For locally, you can enable IntelliTrace, but you would have to add the add-in by hand." What add in, and what does it mean to add the add-in by hand? The answer there also refers to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/07/using-intellitrace-to-debug-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx), but that discusses only how to enable IntelliTrace for applications that have already been deployed to the Windows Azure cloud and does not address using IntelliTrace in the Development Fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellitrace doesn't work against the local dev fabric. You have to deploy your application to get Intellitrace to work. More about debugging Azure apps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee405479.aspx).

Comment: The link doesn't explicitly say that the compute emulator does not support Intellitrace, but you seem to be correct. Given that it takes a while to publish, this is a major weakness, especially when you just want to debug some unit tests.

Comment: Not just that, running on Azure just to debug via Intellitrace costs additional $ !